# counting the matched lines

Tags: text-processing, grep

I have 2 input files. Input file1 looks like this

```
Equus caballus
Monodelphis domestica
Saccharomyces cerevisiae S288c
```

Input2 looks like this(showing first 10 lines)

```
>CM000377.2/60448635-60448529 Equus caballus chromosome 1, whole genome shotgun sequence.   ATCGCTTCTCGGCCTTTTGGCTAAGATCAAGTGTAGTATCTATTCTTATCAGTTTAAAACTAGTGGTGAAATGAGATGTAGACAGTAACATTTGAATTACAACATCA
>CM000377.2/105043590-105043453 Equus caballus chromosome 1, whole genome shotgun sequence. ATTGCTTCTTGGCCTTTTGGCTAAGATCAAGTATAGTATCTGTTCTCATCAATTTAAAAATGGCAATATAAATAGACCCATAGTAGATCCAGATAATGGTGTTATCAGAAAAGGACTTTAAGTAATTTAATATGTTCA
>CM000377.2/137942042-137941941 Equus caballus chromosome 1, whole genome shotgun sequence. ATCGCTTCTCAGACTTTTGGCTAAGATCAAGCGTAGTATCTGTTCTTATCAGTAATTAACTTCAGAAAAGTTAACTCATCTTCAGCAAGGCAGTAATCCCCT
>CM000377.2/97988860-97989002 Equus caballus chromosome 1, whole genome shotgun sequence.   ATCGCTTCTTGGCCTTTTGGCTAAGATCAAGTGTAGGAATCAATGAATTTCTGGTTATGGAGGCTAAAATGATATCTAATCTTGACTTAATCTAGGTCTCTTCAGTATTTGTCACCCTTTACTACATTCTCTGCTGATGCACT
>CM000377.2/77415658-77415776 Equus caballus chromosome 1, whole genome shotgun sequence.   ACTGCTTCTTCGCCTTTTGGCTAAAATCAAGTATAGTATCTGTTCTTACCAGTTTAAGTACTTTTTGTGCTTCTCATGGCTATAAGCCATAATTGCTGTTATAACGGTAAGGATTTTTC
>CM000377.2/172045138-172045024 Equus caballus chromosome 1, whole genome shotgun sequence. ATTGCTTCTTGGCCTTTCAGCTAAGATCAAGTGTTGTATCTGTTCGTATCAGTTTAAATCATTCTGCACCAAAGATATGTCTCTTCTTCTCCATTTATTAATTTGTTCACTTATT
>CM000378.2/50070490-50070688 Equus caballus chromosome 2, whole genome shotgun sequence.   ATTGCTTCTCGGCCTTTTGGCTAAGATCAAGTGTAGTAATTGATTATCTCAAGTTAAGGAGAACTCACTACATCCCAAAGTCTCATTCTTTGTCTGAGTCTTGACACACATACTTCTTTCTGTGAGTATGTCCCTATTGCCTGCAATTGGCAATCTAAACATTCAGTGAAAATCTTCATTAGCTTTGAATGAACCATGT
>CM000378.2/21366877-21367061 Equus caballus chromosome 2, whole genome shotgun sequence.   AAAGCGTCTCAGCCTTTTGGCTAAGATCAAGTGTAGTATCTGTAGCTAGTCTATAACCTGATTGATATGTCCATTTTACCCCAATATCATACCATTATGATTACTGTGGCTTTATATAGCAAATCTTGAACTCAGGTAGTATAAATCCTCTAACTCTGTTCTTTGTCAAAATGGTCTTGGCTATT
>CM000378.2/56987690-56987788 Equus caballus chromosome 2, whole genome shotgun sequence.   ATCGCTTCTCGGCCTTTTGGCTAAGATCAAGTGTAGTATCTGAACGTCGGCGCCCTCGTGAGGAGGCACAGCCTCTCGTTCCCTGCTCCTACACTCCTT
>CM000378.2/18244103-18244249 Equus caballus chromosome 2, whole genome shotgun sequence.   ATCGCTTCTCGGCCTTTTGGCTGAGATCAAGTGTAGAGCTTTGAATAGTATAATAATATTATTTTGATAGTAATAACAATAAACAATCGCTAGCATTAATGAGAGCTTAGTGTATGCCAGTCACCATGCTAAGTGCTCTAGATGCTT
>CM000370.1/74459482-74459563 Monodelphis domestica chromosome 3, whole genome shotgun sequence.    ATCACTTCTCTGCCTTTTGGCTAAGATCAAGTGTAGTATCAATAGATGCAGAAAGAGCTTTTGACAAAATACAACACCCATT
>CM000370.1/105243828-105243703 Monodelphis domestica chromosome 3, whole genome shotgun sequence.  ATTGTTTCTTGGCCTTTTGGCTAAGATCAAGTGTAGAAATATTGTTAAATAATTACTTGTAAGATCTCGGAGAAACTAGAGAAGGTATTTATTGTACCTGGGAGTTTCCCATTCCTGGAACTCTCT
>CM000370.1/143474511-143474342 Monodelphis domestica chromosome 3, whole genome shotgun sequence.  ATTGCTTCTCAACCTTTTGGCTAAGATCAAGTGTAGTATCTATATCCCAATGATGTTTGGGATACTTAGTATTTGGGCAGCTAGAACTCCTCTTCCTGAGTTAAAATCCAGCCAATCACTAGCTGTGTGGCCTTGGGTAAGTCACTTAACCCAGTTTGCCTCAGTTGTCT
>CM000371.1/104846407-104846597 Monodelphis domestica chromosome 4, whole genome shotgun sequence.  ATCGCTTCTCGGCCTTTTGGCTAAGATCAAGTGTAGTATCTGTTCTTATCAGTTTAATATCTGATACGTCCTCTATCCGAGGACAATATATTAAATGGATTTTTGAAGCAGGGAGTCGGAATAGGAGCTTGCTCCGTCCACTCCACGCATCGACCTGGTATTGCAGTACTTCCAGGAACGGTGCACCTCCC
>CM000371.1/104773987-104774177 Monodelphis domestica chromosome 4, whole genome shotgun sequence.  ATCGCTTCTCGGCCTTTTGGCTAAGATCAAGTGTAGTATCTGTTCTTATCAGTTTAATATCTGATACGTCCTCTATCCGAGGACAATATATTAAATGGATTTTTGAAACAGGGAGTCGGAATAGGAGCTTGCTCCGTCCACTCCACGCATCGACCTGGTATTGCAGTACTTCCAGGAACGGTGCACTTCCC
>BK006936.2/681858-681747 TPA: Saccharomyces cerevisiae S288c chromosome II, complete sequence. ATCTCTTTGCCTTTTGGCTTAGATCAAGTGTAGTATCTGTTCTTTTCAGTGTAACAACTGAAATGACCTCAATGAGGCTCATTACCTTTTAATTTGTTACAATACACATTTT
```

I want to grep lines from input file2 which has matched from input file1 and count them to get total number of times the line in input file1 occurs in input file2

example of output

```
Equus caballus 10
Monodelphis domestica 5
Saccharomyces cerevisiae S288c 1
```

and so on.

I have used this to extract from input2 file matched lines in file1

```
grep -Fwf input1 input2
```

How can I count how many times each line in input1 occurs in input2?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
perl -lne '
    $h{"$_"}=$h[@h]=$_,next if @ARGV && !exists $h{$_};
    for my $h (@h) { 1+index(s/\h+/ /rg, " $h chromosome ") && $s{$h}++; }
    }{print "$_ $s{$_}" for @h;
' file1 file2
```

**Output:**

```
Equus caballus 10
Monodelphis domestica 5
Saccharomyces cerevisiae S288c 1
```

**Explanation:**

- `-n` will invoke `Perl` read file line by line AND no printing unless asked to.
- `-l` will make `RS = ORS = \n`
- Data structures involved:

  - hash `%h` will have keys as genes read from `file1`.
  - array `@h` will have genes (non-dup) in the order they were encountered while reading from `file1`.
  - hash `%s` shall have keys have genes and values as number of times this gene was seen in `file2`.
- Working:

  - `@ARGV` shall have contents of 1 file when reading the first argument(file1) and empty when reading the second argument(file2). Hence, the first line will apply to `file` only and will populate the hash `%h` and array `@h`.
  - The second line will apply to lines read from `file2` and will update the hash `%s` to the number of times a particular gene was found on a given line.

    - `index(str, substr)` function will return the postion of the substring in the string if found, otw a -1 is returned on failure.
  - The 3rd line will run after the file2 has been read, and the contents of the hash `%s` are printed based on the order of keys set by the array `@h`.

Answer (score 4):

You can accomplish this with the following:

```
grep -Fowf input1 input2 | sort | uniq -c
```

This will produce the output backwards from the way you want it, but if you need them in that order you can do:

```
grep -Fowf input1 input2 | sort | uniq -c | awk '{c = $1; $1 = ""; print $0,c}'
```

Comment: I just read about -o option
 -o, --only-matching
              Print only the matched (non-empty) parts of a matching line, with each such part on a separate output line.

Thanks

Answer (score 2):

You could do this using arrays in Awk:

```
awk '
  NR==FNR {a[$0]==1; next} 
  {for(x in a) c[x] += $0 ~ x} 
  END {for (x in a) print x, c[x]}
' input1 input2
Equus caballus 10
Saccharomyces cerevisiae S288c 1
Monodelphis domestica 5
```

(It could be done with a single array but IMHO it's cleaner with separate arrays for the index set and the count.)

Comment: If (any of) the needles can contain a regexp-special char like dot star parens or backslash, which for this type data they probably don't, use `index($0,x)>0`

Answer (score 1):

Here's a Python script that does what you want:

```py
#!/usr/bin/env python
"""Count the occurrences of the lines in file1 inside file2."""

import sys

path1 = sys.argv[1]
path2 = sys.argv[2]

counts = dict()
with open(path1, 'r') as file1:
    for line1 in file1.read().splitlines():
        counts[line1] = 0
        with open(path2, 'r') as file2:
            for line2 in file2.read().splitlines():
                if line1 in line2:
                    counts[line1] += 1

for key, value in counts.iteritems():
    print("{}: {}".format(key, value))
```

You could run it like this:

```bsh
python count.py file1 file2
```

On your given example data it gives the following output:

```
Monodelphis domestica: 5
Saccharomyces cerevisiae S288c: 1
Equus caballus: 10
```

And here's a Bash script that does the same thing:

```bsh
#!/bin/bash

file1 = "$1"
file2 = "$2"

while read line; do
    count="$(grep -F "${line}" file2 | wc -l)"; echo "${line}: ${count}";
done < file1
```